# Обновить (Перерисовать окно) в QML

Tags: qt, qml

Имеются два QML окна, во втором меняется содержимое первого, когда закрываю второе окно, то в первом изменения не применяются. Вопрос: каким методом можно обновить окно (перерисовать его)?

Comment: Опишите подробнее, как второе окно меняет содержимое первого. Возможно, что здесь и будет проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Написал код, который полностью обновляет окно. Для этого вам нужно создать класс "backend" в c++, который в конструкторе получит ссылку на QQuickView и в НОВОМ потоке запустить setSource. Если сделать в текущем, программа упадёт. Делается это через 2 слота, один публичный, другой приватный. Вызываем из Qml публичный слот, в нем запускаем приватный в новом потоке

```
QUrl url(str);
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "loadnewurl", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(QUrl, url));
```

Вот исходный код на github, надеюсь поможет https://github.com/tripolskypetr/qmlloadnewmarkup
Работает на Android и Windows

Answer (score -1):

Такого метода нет. Можно только полностью разрушить QML объект и создать новый. 
Но окно можно обновить (перерисовать в нем по одному все что надо перерисовать). Для этого вам нужно просто подписаться на сигнал закрытия второго окна, и в слоте подписанном на этот сигнал обновить содержимое главного окна.

Comment: Под обновить вы понимаете разрушить и создать заново?

Comment: Нет, обновить - это значит просто переписать все надписи в окошке, перерисовать все кнопки. Например у меня был случай со сменой локализации на ходу - и там работал только вариант разрушить и создать объект заново. А в вашем случае скорее всего достаточно простого обновления всего руками.